# How to move a line diagonally (on a canvas) in python?

Tags: python, vector, pygame

I am using `SimpleGui` and `pygame` modules to develop a game on python. I have a line and its coordinates as shown below:
[image]
I am interested in moving the line diagonally in the direction of an arrow for which I will require to update the coordinates before drawing it on canvas. I am confused as how to update the `x` and `y` coordinates to move the line in desired direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose `N` to get step size

```
dx = (x1-x2)/N
dy = (y1-y2)/N
```

and then you can move

```
x1 += dx
y1 += dy

x2 += dx
y2 += dy
```

Comment: Thanks @furas, that did help.